# Android studio okhttp and Retrofit failed gradle execution

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

Seems I added this line

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
```

I got this error: Failed to complete gradle execution

I allready have retrofit installed.
Android Studio 1.2.2

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the missing space after `compile`?

Try it like this: `compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'`

Comment: Sorry about that, just bad copy, I will reedit my question. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

From OkHttp site

> You'll also need Okio, which OkHttp uses for fast I/O and resizable buffers. Download the latest JAR.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Still got the same error anyway.